# Python matplotlib.plot the pointe messed up due to the picture size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey everyone! I use the python matplotlib.plot to draw a line

Here is my data

```
x = ['1000', '5950', '10900', '15850', '20800', '25750', '30700', '35650', '40600', '45550', '50500', '55450', '60400', '65350', '70300', '75250', '80200', '85150', '90100', '95050', '100000']
y = ['0.003383', '0.16341', '0.543723', '1.19463', '2.12827', '3.33978', '4.70849', '6.46607', '8.52736', '11.2711', '14.3101', '18.176', '26.1123', '32.0252', '31.692', '43.1399', '48.2962', '48.2436', '52.6464', '61.8072', '68.8354']
```

I write this in IPython

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

and it gived me this
[check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGtYi.png)

I mean, according to the `x` `y` list, it should a **Increasing** curve.
So, can someone can assist?
I will appreciate if you give any advice:)

Comment: This happens because your lists contain _strings_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the lists you are using contain *strings*. What you actually want are integers for `x`, and floats for `y`. In order to do this you can cast the contents of the lists to either `int` or `float` using a list comprehension.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['1000', '5950', '10900', '15850', '20800', '25750', '30700', '35650', '40600', '45550',
     '50500', '55450', '60400', '65350', '70300', '75250', '80200', '85150', '90100', '95050', '100000']
y = ['0.003383', '0.16341', '0.543723', '1.19463', '2.12827', '3.33978', '4.70849', '6.46607',
     '8.52736', '11.2711', '14.3101', '18.176', '26.1123', '32.0252', '31.692', '43.1399', '48.2962', '48.2436',
     '52.6464', '61.8072', '68.8354']

# Convert contents of lists
new_x = [int(i) for i in x]
new_y = [float(j) for j in y]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.set_title("List of strings")

ax2.plot(new_x,new_y)
ax2.set_title("Lists have been converted")

plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image]